# deploy nodejs modbus-rtu using the modbus-serial library to HEROKU

Tags: node.js, heroku, serial-port, modbus

Recently, i want to deploy nodejs to heroku using modbus-serial library and socket.io, the idea here is i want to retrieve temperature real time from pt100 using serial RS-485, 
locally, the code run well having no problem, but went i deploy to heroku, it seems like heroku didnt recognize the usb port "/dev/ttyUSB0",here what i got, 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0,
its because heroku doesnt know what it is, or do i have to set the environment variable for the usb port,

here my code,

```
 const ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial")
    const client = new ModbusRTU()

    const app = require('http').createServer(server)
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)

    const io = require("socket.io")(app)

      io.on("connection",function(socket){
        client.connectRTUBuffered("/dev/ttyUSB0", { baudRate: 115200 }).then(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        client.writeFC3(1,0,2,(err,data) => {
          if(err)console.log("error ",err)
          console.log("datas ",data)
          io.emit("datas_holding_register_rtu",{ datas : data["data"] })
        })
      },100)
    })

        socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'))
    })
```

any idea what happening here ? thank you

sincerely,
toni

Answer (score 0):

So... Heroku is a cloud system, and serial communication occurs LOCALLY WITH a cable attached to your computer to the USB port. So, Heroku cannot communicate with your device, because it doesn't have an USB port. Solution: Run your code on a computer connected to the usb cable.